# Store data issue in java

Tags: java

I've just written some code to form some statistics in java:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte[]  weekEval = new byte[18];
        String  weekMatch = "";
        byte    order = -1;

        while (++order < 18) {
            byte    tmpRes = 10;
            byte    count = 5;
            if (sc.hasNextByte())
                weekMatch += sc.nextByte();
            Scanner scInScope = new Scanner(weekMatch);

            weekMatch = scInScope.findInLine("Week \\d+");
            if (weekMatch == null) {
                System.err.println("Illegal Argument");
                sc.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            String  orderMatch = "Week " + (order + 1);
            if (!orderMatch.equals(weekMatch)) {
                System.err.println("Illegal argument");
                sc.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            weekMatch = "";
            for (byte readData = 0; readData < 5; ++readData) {
                if (sc.hasNext())
                    weekMatch += sc.next();
                else {
                    System.err.println("Illegal argument");
                    sc.close();
                    scInScope.close();
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                weekMatch += ' ';
            }
            scInScope = new Scanner(weekMatch);
            weekMatch = scInScope.findInLine("\\d \\d \\d \\d \\d");
            if (weekMatch == null) {
                System.err.println("Illegal Argument");
                sc.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            scInScope = new Scanner(weekMatch);
            while (count-- > 0) {
                tmpRes = scInScope.nextByte();
                if (weekEval[order] > tmpRes)
                    weekEval[order] = tmpRes;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 18 && weekEval[i] != 10; ++i) {
            System.out.print("Week " + (i + 1) + ' ');
            while (weekEval[i]-- > 0)
                System.out.printf("=");
            System.out.println(">");
        }
        sc.close();
```

It works, but I need to complete task without arrays. Ok, I have String at least, right? Wrong. Any String concatenation within a loop is forbidden. The only string method I'm allowed to use is string.equals. There are also system.out, system.err and scanner(System.in). I ran out of ideas, what trick i can use...

Comment: Telling us what the program is supposed to do would help.

Comment: You can "fake" concatenation with multiple `System.out.print` calls. Each will output directly after the previous. Then do a println to insert then newline. Eg. `S.o.print("Week "); S.o.print(i + 1); S.o.print(" ")` etc. Or you should shove stuff into a StringBuilder and then print/concat outside of the loop.

Comment: I don't know what it is you want to do, but can't you use recursion to avoid loops?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca
Well here's a subject
Customer evaluates this progress as a minimal grade for five tests within each week. Each test can be graded between 1 and 9.
The maximum number of weeks for the analysis is 18. Once the program has obtained information for each week, it displays the graph on the console to show minimum grades for a specific week.
And we keep assuming that 42 is the input data limit.
The exact guaranteed number of tests in a week is 5.
However, the order of weekly data input is not guaranteed, so Week 1’s data can be entered after Week 2’s data.

Comment: Second part of subject: If data input order is wrong the program shall be shut down with -1 code.


• There are many options for storing information, and arrays are just one of them. Apply another method for storing data about student tests without the use of arrays.
• String concatenation often results in unexpected program behavior. If there are many iterations of a concatenation operation in a cycle for a single variable, an application may slow down significantly. That is why we should not use string concatenation inside a loop to generate a result.

Comment: @BartBarnard I thought about that, but all class methods are forbidden and only one file is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first, I want to apologize for not posting subject and so unclear question. So the task is next:

*Customer evaluates this progress as a minimal grade for five tests within each week. Each test can be graded between 1 and 9.*

*The maximum number of weeks for the analysis is 18. Once the program has obtained information for each week, it displays the graph on the console to show minimum grades for a specific week.*

*And we keep assuming that 42 is the input data limit.
The exact guaranteed number of tests in a week is 5.*

*However, the order of weekly data input is not guaranteed, so Week 1’s data can be entered after Week 2’s data. If data input order is wrong, IllegalArgument message shall be displayed, and the program shall be shut down with -1 code.*

The problem was in the very-very confusing notes

**Note:**

*• There are many options for storing information, and arrays are just one of them. Apply another method for storing data about student tests without the use of arrays.*

*• String concatenation often results in unexpected program behavior. If there are many iterations of a concatenation operation in a cycle for a single variable, an application may slow down significantly. That is why we should not use string concatenation inside a loop to generate a result.*

In before, '->' stands for the user input. So, overall, it should be looked like:

```
-> Week 1
-> 4 5 2 4 2
-> Week 2
-> 7 7 7 7 6
-> Week 3
-> 4 3 4 9 8
-> Week 4
-> 9 9 4 6 7
-> 42
Week 1 ==>
Week 2 ======>
Week 3 ===>
Week 4 ====>
```

The core trick hides in java.utils.scanner and some very handy regex formulas. The final solution is below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte    roll = 0;
        long    multModif = 1;
        long    result = 0;

        sc.useDelimiter("\\u000A");
        while (roll < 18) {
            byte    tool = 0;

            if (sc.hasNext("(42)|(Week(\\s)(\\d))")) {
                sc.useDelimiter("\\s+");

                String verify = sc.next();
                if (verify.equals("42"))
                    break ;
                tool = sc.nextByte();
                sc.useDelimiter("\\u000A");
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Illegal Argument");
                sc.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            if (tool != ++roll) {
                System.err.println("Illegal Argument");
                sc.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            tool = 10;
            if (sc.hasNext("(\\d)(\\s)(\\d)(\\s)(\\d)(\\s)(\\d)(\\s)(\\d)")) {
                sc.useDelimiter("\\s+");
                for (byte i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                    byte toolTmp = sc.nextByte();
                    if (tool > toolTmp)
                        tool = toolTmp;
                }
                sc.useDelimiter("\\u000A");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Illegal Argument");
                sc.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            result += tool * multModif;
            multModif *= 10;
        }
        for (byte i = 0; i < roll; ++i) {
            byte weekRes;

            weekRes = (byte)(result % 10);
            result /= 10;
            System.out.print("Week ");
            System.out.print(i + 1);
            System.out.print(' ');
            for (byte j = 0; j < weekRes; ++j)
                System.out.print('=');
            System.out.println('>');
        }
    }
}
```

I made it through some tests, but, frankly to say, not 100% sured about accuracy of my solution, but it works and satisfies noted mentioned above. That you guys for assistance, and big sorry for so confusing question...